# 301 Redirect links from old categories to the new categories

Tags: magento-1.9, 301-redirect

I moved my website from `Opencart` to Magento and also renamed all categories.

So now I do have a lot of broken links that I would like to redirect to their new categories.

For example I have :
https://www.umweltfreunde.com/Wertstoffsammler-Abfalltrennsysteme/stahlblech-trenn-systeme

and now all links in the Wertstoffsammler-Abfalltrennsysteme/* should go to the new category :
https://www.umweltfreunde.com/abfall-und-entsorgung/wertstoffsammler-und-abfalltrennsysteme

So I have about 5 old categories and hundreds of links under them that needs to redirect to the new category.

The older products are no longer in use, so I want to redirect the products to their category so the customer will see the category instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think best option for you is from `.htaccess` file.

You can add these lines in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
##comment upper 2 lines if these are already set in your htaccess
RewriteRule ^Wertstoffsammler-Abfalltrennsysteme/(.*) https://www.umweltfreunde.com/Wertstoffsammler-Abfalltrennsysteme/stahlblech-trenn-systeme/$1 [R=301,L]
```

[Ref](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8665/how-to-301-redirect-category-to-customname)